# New Ceiling light old wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling, old-house

Am putting a new ceiling light but the old light has 5 wires and the new ceiling light has 3 slots. The old light has 2 black ones in neutral and one in line, 2 reds in loop and the bare wire that’s earth.
I know one black needs to go in neutral, the other black in live and the earth in earth but where does the 2 red wire go?
My light won’t work when I don’t add them but when I remove the earth an add the 2 red in the earth then the light works.

It just has neutral, live & earth [image]

That’s the new light
[image]

And the old one
[image]

Can I keep it like that as it works and put the earth wire away or is that going to cause problems? This is the only way the light would work.

Comment: Please do _not_ ask the same question again to include a new picture. Simply edit the original one (click the "Edit" text below the tags) and include the additional picture with the original question.

Comment: It won’t let me post a picture when I edit it

Comment: Then upload the picture to imgur.com (SE's image hosting partner) and put the link in the comments. Someone will embed the second picture for you.

Comment: Am trying I can’t am new to this it’s abit complicated! I just need help with my light

Comment: I've inlined both to the original post - & pushed colour so we can actually see what the wires are. Still can't read any labelling on the new fitting, but for sure someone's going to electrocute themselves eventually, guessing that badly.

Comment: I tried pushing the wire that the closest I could get the black one in natural and one In LINE and the red in LOOP..

Comment: Stop playing with it at random. Either something will go bang, or you'll electrocute yourself. See back to your original question. We need a clear picture of how that new block works. BTW, the original rose was the acme of sense & sensibility. The new block is dumb as dumb can be.

Comment: I have put an answer on your other question.  **The way you have wired it is a death trap and is waiting to kill you next time you go to change the bulb.**